# Function stopping

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm having an issue where I'm calling a function to display text when a dropdown is selected.

The issue is that no matter which dropdown is selected it only displays the text from the first option.
 When I look at the actual code I See I'm calling function jumpto and getting the variable that is within the `document > form2 > of the menu> option and its index # > and the value of that option`. And everything looks correct, but it will only pull the text I have for the new user but not the new user ag. Any help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script language="JavaScript">
function jumpto(x)
{
   if (document.form2.jumpmenu.value = "New User")
   {
       text to display here about creating a new user
   }
   else if (document.form2.jumpmenu.value = "New User AG")
   {
       text to display about creating a use in a different department
   }

<form name="form2">
<select name="jumpmenu" onChange="jumpto(document.form2.jumpmenu.options[document.form2.jumpmenu.options.selectedIndex].value)">
<option>Jump to...</option>
<option value="New User" id="New User">New User</option>
<option value="New User AG" id="New User AG">New User AG</option
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: FYI, you can just write `document.form2.value` instead of having to using `selectedIndex`.

Comment: Why is the function getting the value by itself instead of using the `x` parameter?

Comment: @brk is right. you can't use a single `=` in an ifstatement. it needs to be `==` or `===`

Comment: @FllnAngl of course you can use it, but that doesn't change its meaning. That does not make it a comparison. It's still an assignment. But you can use a value assignment inside an if-statement; it's a valid expression.

Comment: Also you pass the value and then test the select. This could much more elegantly be written  `onChange="jumpTo(this.value)"` and then test `if (x === "New User") ...`

Comment: also need to change onChange to onchange, all lower case. This could be better designed, for sure... try using this for the jumpto `function jumpto(){
  const newVal = document.getElementById('jumpmenu').value;
  console.log(newVal);
}` and the select should look like this: `<select id="jumpmenu" onchange="jumpto()">`

Comment: @Thomas well alright yeah it's valid but not in the way he or she wants it :)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I ended up doing what I needed a different way, but the tips here helped me learn something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace single equals in `if(document.form2.jumpmenu.value = "New User")` with triple equals like `if(document.form2.jumpmenu.value === "New User")`. Single equal will just assign the value but here you need to check the truthiness of the value  Same for `else if` also

Comment: `if (x === "New User")`